# Java annotation values

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I have several annotations, among them an annotation with some values:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(PARAMETER)
public @interface Size {
     int min() default 1;
     int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Now I have some code that needs to read all such values of an annotation dynamically, and get the type and value of the fields. So I do not want to perform a check for the type of annotation I've got, but rather do it more dynamically. I notice that the annotation is somewhat like an interface with some methods, so I was thinking I maybe could do this:

```
Method[] methods = annotation.annotationType().getMethods();

Class<?>[] constructorParams = new Class<?>[methods.length];
Object[] values = new Object[methods.length];
int i = 0;
for(Method m : methods) {
    constructorParams[i] = m.getReturnType();
    values[i++] = m.invoke(annotation);
}

Constructor<? extends CustomValidator> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(constructorParams);
return constructor.newInstance(values);
```

Will this work? Is there another better aproach?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? The only issue I see is that you are making the assumption that every method is a zero-argument method.

Comment: well, @interface methods cannot have parameters.

Answer (score 0):

ok, given the above code, changing this statement:

```
Method[] methods = annotation.annotationType().getMethods();
```

with this statement

```
Method[] methods = annotation.annotationType().getDeclaredMethods();
```

fixes it